# Pegar um valor dentro do HTML cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou querendo pegar um valor que está dentro do html de uma pagina

```
<a href="https://www.site.com/user.asp?ref=fvFCF9D8N4Ak">
```

quero pegar apenas  o valor `ref=fvFCF9D8N4Ak`

estou usando cURL e php e pensei que a solução era uma regex .

mais como eu devo pega esse valor ?

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que estás a fazer uso de [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) para puxar o HTML de um endereço, e depois a usar o PHP para recolher determinados dados do HTML recolhido:

Podes fazer uso da classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) para fazer o *parse* do HTML, localizar a tag `<a/>` e recolher o valor do atributo `href`.

Depois fazendo uso da função [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) podes extrair a *query string* do mesmo, sendo isso o que pretendes:

### Exemplo

```
// o HTML que recolheste
$html = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.site.com/user.asp?ref=fvFCF9D8N4Ak">bubu</a>
</body>
</html>';

// Instanciar o DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument;

// Carregar o HTML recolhido para o DOMDocument
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Percorrer o DOM e por cada tag 'a' encontrada
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {

    // apanhar o valor do atributo 'href'
    $href = $tag->getAttribute('href');

    // se não estiver vazio
    if (!empty($href)) {

        // guardar a query string numa variável
        $queryString = parse_url($href, PHP_URL_QUERY);  // Resultado: ref=fvFCF9D8N4Ak
    }
}
```

Ver exemplo a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/FQoWTY).

---

Se só tens o HTML presente na pergunta, o método é exactamente o mesmo:

```
$html = '<a href="https://www.site.com/user.asp?ref=fvFCF9D8N4Ak">';
 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
 
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
 
    $href = $tag->getAttribute('href');
 
    if (!empty($href)) {
 
        $queryString = parse_url($href, PHP_URL_QUERY); // Resultado: ref=fvFCF9D8N4Ak
    }
}
```

Ver exemplo a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/m3QYrQ).

Answer (score 0):

Olá amigo você pode tentar essa solução com Regex ( Fiz uma classe simples para o teste) :

```
<?php

/**
 * A simple crawler
 * By Rodrigo Nascimento
 * 
 */
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Class SimpleCrawler {

    private $url;
    private $userAgent;
    private $httpResponse;

    function __construct() {
        $this->userAgent       = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0";
        $this->chocolateCookie = "chocolateCookies.txt";
    }

    /**
     * Seta a url alvo
     * @param string $url
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    public function setUrl($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Requisição get
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    private function get(){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->chocolateCookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->chocolateCookie);
        $this->httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Pega o conteudo da requisição
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    public function getPageContent() {
        return $this->httpResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Faz a navegação na página especificado por self::setUrl
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    public function navigate() {
        $this->get();

        return $this;
    }
}

/* Estancia do nosso objeto que se baseia nos seguintes métodos:
 * 
 * Definir uma url: $simpleCrawler->setUrl('site');
 * Navegar em dada url: $simpleCrawler->navigate();
 * E por fim ter acesso ao conteúdo da requisição: $simpleCrawler->getPageContent();
 * 
 */

$simpleCrawler = new SimpleCrawler;
$simpleCrawler->setUrl("http://siteQualquer")
              ->navigate();

$conteudo  = $simpleCrawler->getPageContent();
$urlResult = (preg_match("#?ref=(.*?)\">#", $conteudo, $match)) ? $match[1] 
                                                                : "Não foi possível obter a url solicitada via Regex.";

echo $urlResult . PHP_EOL;
```