# Varrer todas as paginas, curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Eu preciso acessar um site através do cURL e capturar conteúdos da pagina dele, porém ele nao mostra todo conteudo em uma pagina só, ele as divide em varias paginas  no final ele mostra aquele menu para navegar pela página 1, 2, 3, 4, preciso andar por TODAS essas paginas para poder capturar o conteudo que desejo, como posso realizar?

O codigo desse "menu" (esqueci o nome disso) é esse:

```
<center><div class='wp-pagenavi'>
<span class='pages'>1 de 8</span><span class='current'>1</span><a class="page larger" href="/page/2/">2</a><a class="page larger" href="/page/3/">3</a><span class='extend'>...</span><a class="nextpostslink" rel="next" href="/page/2/">></a><a class="last" href="/page/8/">»</a>
</div></center>
```

Nesse caso eu precisaria navegar pelas 8 paginas para obter o que eu quero, como fazer?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: @Andre Ribeiro apenas lógica

Comment: dê uma olhada nesta resposta: [Link][1]


  [1]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43729/pegar-um-valor-dentro-do-html-curl?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa efetuar uma requisição para cada página e capturar o conteúdo dentro das mesmas.

Supondo que a url inicio seja:
    http://site.com/page/1

Logo podemos criar uma classe para efetuar o "crawler" em todas as páginas com um laço for simples ( Com a classe já pronta ):

```
<?php

/**
 * A simple crawler
 * By Rodrigo Nascimento
 * 
 */
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Class SimpleCrawler {

    private $url;
    private $userAgent;
    private $httpResponse;

    function __construct() {
        $this->userAgent       = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0";
        $this->chocolateCookie = "chocolateCookies.txt";
    }

    /**
     * Seta a url alvo
     * @param string $url
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    public function setUrl($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Requisição get
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    private function get(){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->chocolateCookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->chocolateCookie);
        $this->httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Pega o conteudo da requisição
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    public function getPageContent() {
        // Aqui vc pode fazer o parse do content da página utilizando regex ou seja
        // lá qual for o método utilizado.
        echo "Page Content:\n\n",
             "{$this->httpResponse}\n\n";

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Faz a navegação na página especificado por self::setUrl
     * @return SimpleCrawler
     */
    public function navigate() {
        echo "Visiting: {$this->url}\n";
        $this->get();

        return $this;
    }
}

/* Estancia do nosso objeto que se baseia nos seguintes métodos:
 * 
 * Definir uma url: $simpleCrawler->setUrl('site');
 * Navegar em dada url: $simpleCrawler->navigate();
 * E por fim ter acesso ao conteúdo da requisição: $simpleCrawler->getPageContent();
 * 
 */
$simpleCrawler = new SimpleCrawler;

// à partir daqui podemos executar quantas requests quisermos.
// Já que precisamos do mesmo site basta um laço simples para efetuar a navegação
$pageNum = 8;

for ($i=1;$i<=$pageNum;$i++):
    $simpleCrawler->setUrl("http://site/page/{$i}")
                  ->navigate()
                  ->getPageContent();
endfor;
```

Isso já deve ser o suficiente para cumprir a missão (: