# Pegar parte de um URL com cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Caros,
estava olhando este tópico [Pegar um valor dentro do html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43729/pegar-um-valor-dentro-do-html-curl) e entendi que usando este recurso "parse_url($href, PHP_URL_QUERY)" o mesmo tem a função de guarda a query string em uma variável.

A minha duvida é a seguinte:
Quero percorrer uma pagina (URL), e localizar todas as urls, no caso, os href que possui apenas um determinado trecho da URL, por exemplo: "/pasta/subpasta/", ou seja, apenas os links que possui aquele trecho na URL.

Olhei alguns exemplo na web, mas não está funcionando corretamente, está imprimindo todas as URLS

Aqui está o que estou tentando resolver:

```
<?php
  $url = "htt´://www.minhaurl.com.br";
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $string = '';
  $nlinks = 0;
  $slinks = 0;
  $meuslinks = array();
  $x=1;
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);

  foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $link) {
    $string = $link->getAttribute("href");
    if(strpos($string,"/pasta/subpasta/") == false){
        $slinks++;
    }else{
        if(strpos($string,"/pasta/subpasta/") == true){
            $exibe = "<a href='".$string."'>".$string."</a>";
            echo $exibe."<br>";
            $nlinks++;
            $meuslinks[$nlinks] = $exibe;
        }
    }
  }
  $tam = sizeof($meuslinks);
  while($x <= $tam){
    echo $meuslinks[$x]."<br>";
    $x++;
  }
  echo "<br> ".$nlinks." links foram encontrados!<br>";
  echo "<br> ".$slinks." links foram encontrados!<br>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Olha eu fiz assim e deu certo, veja:

```
$conteudo = file_get_contents("https://www.uol.com.br/");
$regexLinks = "/[w]*[A-z0-9]{1,}[\.]{1}[A-z0-9]*[A-z\.0-9_\/-]*/";
preg_match_all($regexLinks, $conteudo, $links, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL);
$hrefs =  $links[0];
$busca = "/mercado/2018/"; // links que contem os diretórios "mercado" e "2018"
$cont = 0;
$urls = array();

foreach($hrefs as $link){

    if(strpos($link, $busca)){
        $cont++;
        $urls[] = $link;
    }

}
if($cont == 0){
    echo "nenhum link encontrado";
    die();
}
echo "Total de links encontrados: ";
echo $cont."</br>";

foreach($urls as $url){
    echo "<a href='$url'>".$url."</a></br>";
}
```